# Editing a VF page embedded in a Std page layout?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

On my opportunity page layout, I want to embed a related record from another object  with VF. Can they edit that VF page within the parent Std page?  So more specifically

Std page = view mode, VF  = edit?

std page = edit mode, VF = edit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visualforce pages won't appear in edit mode on standard page layouts. Visualforce pages on the standard page's detail view may be in view or edit mode, depending on your needs. Specifically:

> Std page = view mode, VF = edit?

Yes (pages embedded in a standard page may update records)

> std page = edit mode, VF = edit?

No (cannot have any Visualforce page inside a standard edit page)

Comment: Technically you could write a VF page that leveraged the apex:detail tag to give the appearance that you are on the standard page, and then append some VF tags at the bottom. By doing this, and then replacing the standard New/Edit/View pages with this custom page.

Comment: Technically yes Michael but then you have to write code instead of simple drag and drop to update standard pages plus if you have many layouts it becomes tedious, we tend to try to avoid this wherever possible. In this case user training to edit on the view page would be more appropriate.